# ng-click not firing even I registered the function in controller

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am working on an app and get the problem. I checked console but no error messages.

I created a component and I insert it into other template. Template itself is working(button is rendered and I inspected the element ng-click attribute is there) but when I click on the button. the function is not fired.

The project is availiable here: https://github.com/Aozaki-Touko/webApplication-dota2hero/tree/master/app

navbar.component.js:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("navbar").component("navbar", {
  templateUrl: "/navbar/navbar.template.html",
  controller: [
    "$location",
    function($location) {
      var self=this;
      self.changeToHeroes = function(){
        alert("Button Pressed!");
        $location.path("/heroes");
      };
    }
  ]
});
```

navbar.template.html:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.changePathToHeroes()">Heroes</button>
```

navbar.module.js:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("navbar",[]);
```

Comment: Your  method name is misspelled.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. I changed it but problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me.
It seems to me that was a problem with the function name.

```js
"use strict";

angular.module("navbar").component("navbar", {
  templateUrl: "/navbar/navbar.template.html",
  controller: [
    "$location",
    function($location) {
      var self = this;
      function changePathToHeroes(){
        alert("Button Pressedddddd!");
        $location.path("/heroes");
      }
      self.changePathToHeroes = changePathToHeroes;
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.changePathToHeroes();">Heroes</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
<button type="button" ng-click="changePathToHeros()">Heroes</button>
```

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. I changed it but problem remains.

Comment: post how you have mentioned controller in html

Comment: I used the navbar component somewhere else as<navbar></navbar> I didn't explicitly declare controller in html file since it is declared in component file. I tried declare a variable in component controller and use {{variable}} in template, this works. but somehow the function is not registered to click event.

Answer (score 0):

use **controllerAs**

```
angular.module("navbar").component("navbar", {
  templateUrl: "/navbar/navbar.template.html",
  controllerAs:"$ctrl",
  controller: [
    "$location",
    function($location) {
      var $ctrl = this;
      $ctrl .changeToHeroes = function(){
        alert("Button Pressed!");
        $location.path("/heroes");
      };
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Not working. $ctrl is default in component. Using controllerAs in component
 overrides default $ctrl.